# FullCalendar not working MVC 5

Tags: jquery, calendar, fullcalendar, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to display a full calendar but no luck.
I have try to download the fullcalendar from nuGet and included the files but not working.

```
  <script src="~/Scripts/lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/lib/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
    <link href="~/Content/fullcalendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


    <script src="~/Scripts/gcal.js"></script>
    <link href="~/Content/fullcalendar.print.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />


    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            });

        });

    </script>



    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>

</head>
<body>

    <div id='calendar'></div>

</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Also i try the code below and also not working.
What i am doing wrong and how i can show the fullcalendar?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>


    <script src='http://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.1.1/lib/moment.min.js'></script>
    <script src='http://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.1.1/lib/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script src="http://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.1.1/lib/jquery-ui.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script src='http://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.1.1/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            defaultDate: '2014-09-12',
            editable: true,
            eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
        });
    });
    </script>



    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />


    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>

</head>
<body>

    <div id='calendar'></div>

</body>
</html>
```

In Chrome browser inspect elements

[image]

**EDIT 1:**

I have change the code in script and now I got no errors but still not showing anything

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var m = moment('2016-09-19');

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        // put your options and callbacks here
        header: {
            left: 'title',
            center: '',
            right: 'prev,next'
        },
        weekends: false,
        weekNumbers: true,
        defaultView: 'month',
        defaultDate: m,
        events: [{
            start: '2016-09-19',
            allDay: true,
            rendering: 'background',
            backgroundColor: '#F00',
            title: 'full',
            textColor: '#000',
            className: 'event-full'
        }, {
            start: '2016-09-20',
            allDay: true,
            rendering: 'background',
            backgroundColor: '#F00',
            title: 'full',
            textColor: '#000',
            className: 'event-full'
        }],
        eventAfterRender: function (event, element, view) {
            element.append('FULL');
        },
        viewRender: function (view, element) {
            var start = new Date("2016-09-01");
            var end = new Date("2016-11-30");

            if (end < view.end) {
                $("#calendar .fc-next-button").hide();
                return false;
            } else {
                $("#calendar .fc-next-button").show();
            }

            if (view.start < start) {
                $("#calendar .fc-prev-button").hide();
                return false;
            } else {
                $("#calendar .fc-prev-button").show();
            }

        }
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the fullCalendar CSS file. From your examples I can see only fullcalendar.print.css - which will only work when sending the calendar to the printer. Somewhere in the files downloaded by nuget should be "fullcalendar.css". Make sure you include this in the page, otherwise it's very likely nothing will get rendered properly.

See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/usage/ for a very simple example of all the required files and the order in which you must include them. Obviously change the relative paths suggested in the example if they don't match the locations of the files in your solution.